# Find and replace date with UTC date

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, date

I have file that looks like this:

```
[2024-01-20 15:23:00] hello world
[2024-01-20 15:42:00] bye
[2024-01-20 15:43:00] foo bar
...
```

Date in this file are in UTC+1 and I want to convert in to UTC

I tried using `sed` with capture groups:

```sh
cat file | sed -E "s/(([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)? ?([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+))/$(date -d "\1 UTC+1" +%H:%M:%S -u)/g"
```

but I'm getting:

```
date: invalid date ‘\\1 UTC+1’
```

I have tried following replacements of `\1`:

- `"\1"`
- `'\1'`
- `\\1`
- `"\\1"`
- `'\\1'`

None of above worked.

For testing I'm using this one-liner:

```
echo '19:40:14 foo bar' | sed -E "s/([0-9:]+)/$(date -d "\1 UTC+1" -u +%R)/g"
```

Desired result: `19:40:14` -> `18:40:14` in case when timezone is UTC+1

I'm open to using something else rather than `sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU sed for its `e` modifier

```sh
sed -E 's/\[([^]]+)\](.*)/date -ud "\1+01:00" "+[%F %T\2"/e' file
# ........................................................^
```

```
[2024-01-20 14:23:00] hello world
[2024-01-20 14:42:00] bye
[2024-01-20 14:43:00] foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(...)` approach will never work because such expansions processed by the shell, and 'sed' is not part of the shell, meaning that all of the `$` substitutions in the command line happen **before** 'sed' is even run at all – and they are only done once for the entire command.

(It *does not* go back and forth between 'sed' and the shell to be re-expanded for every regex match, nor does everything happen "simultaneously"; there's a certain order of operations.)

For this to work, the date adjustment needs to be done within the same program. 'sed' has no such capabilities; AWK might, although some other language will likely be more convenient.

Write a script in Python, Ruby, PHP, Perl that reads each line from STDIN and does a regex replace – all these languages have a way to use a 'callback function' as the regex replacement (e.g. in Python you can literally pass a function as the parameter, in Perl you use the `/e` regex option).

(Or perform everything *including the regex* in Bash, using a `while read` loop and Bash's `[[ a =~ b ]]` regex match operator.)